# How do I match any word from a cell in one column to another?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

In column A, I have rows of data with surrounding text.
In column C, I have rows of data with a program name and some abbreviations.

Eg :
Please consider bullets as individual rows.

Column A :

- For exams use excel
- Library Management System: ERMSystem
- For vc use skype, zoom.
- For Db: use MySql, T-sql, Oracle (or Postgres)

Column C :

- Zoom
- Ms Skype
- MySql
- Licensed Postgres
- Excel
- Old archived useless ERMSystem

In column D I am trying to find what isn't listed (any occurance) in Column A, compared to Column C. For which I came up with this formula :
Column D : `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&C2&"*",A:A,1,0),"Not Mapped")`
This doesn't work in case of text like `postgres` or `ERMSystem`

How can I achieve matching any word from a given row in a column to any word from any row in another column? The end goal is to highlight applications in Column C which have no mention in column A - which I can do using conditional formatting when I can nail down how to do it.

**Edit:** The issue, I think, is when there are more than one words in the column C. As the formula stands, it does a find on `*Old archived useless ERMSystem*` which doesn't match `Library Management System: ERMSystem` - so, as the title says, I need to find a way to match any word in a column to any word in another column

Comment: The edit has made it much more complicated and explains why you posted. You may need a VBA solution. How do you define a word? Any group of alphabetic characters surrounded by non-alphabetic characters?

Comment: @EngineerToast Yes. Any group of alphabetic characters or number - may or may not necessarily be surrounded by special characters

Answer (score 0):

Your formula works perfectly for me. Only "Ms Skype" is marked as "not matched" and it is correct.

Comment: For clarity: I tried is with the text `postgres` in case the different capitalization was causing an issue and it still worked fine for me, too.

Comment: @lin That is what I am trying to achieve - skype should be matched as 'skype' is used in both columns

Comment: @EngineerToast vlookup is a case insensitive search by default. I have also edited the question and added another scenario that fails (ERMSystem)